# How to build html using HTML helpers in MVC3

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

I've a helper like this, I created this using raw HTML inside as follows:

```
private static readonly Core Db = new Core();
        // Main menu
public static MvcHtmlString MainMenu()
{
    IQueryable<Page> primaryPages = Db.Pages.Where(p => p.IsItShowInMenu);
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Clear();
     string pagecode = Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["url"]);
    sb.Append("<div id=\"Logo\">");
    sb.Append("<a href=\"/\"><span id=\"Logo_Text\">Dr. Shreekumar</span></a> <span id=\"Logo_Sub_Text\">Obstetrician & Gynecologist</span>");
    sb.Append("</div>");
    sb.Append("<div id=\"Primary_Menu\">");
    sb.Append("<ul>");
    foreach (Page page in primaryPages)
    {
        if (page.PageCode != "Home")
        {
             Page currentPage = Db.Pages.SingleOrDefault(p => p.PageCode == pagecode);
             if (currentPage != null)
             {
                  Page parentPage = Db.Pages.Find(currentPage.ParentId);
                  if (parentPage != null)
                  {
                      sb.AppendFormat((page.PageCode == parentPage.PageCode ||
                      page.PageCode == currentPage.PageCode)
                      ? "<li class=\"active\"><a href=\"/pages/{0}\">{1}</a></li>"
                        : "<li><a href=\"/pages/{0}\">{1}</a></li>", page.PageCode,
                              page.Name.Trim());

                  }
                  else
                  {
                     sb.AppendFormat("<li><a href=\"/pages/{0}\">{1}</a></li>", page.PageCode,page.Name);
                  }
              }
              else
              {
                  sb.AppendFormat("<li><a href=\"/pages/{0}\">{1}</a></li>", page.PageCode, page.Name);
              }
        }
    }
    sb.Append("</ul>");
    sb.Append("</div>");
    return new MvcHtmlString(sb.ToString());
 }
```

Can anybody suggest me that how can I convert this using MVC HTML helpers (helpers for anchor, list (li), div etc)

Comment: You shouldn't have any database logic in your HTML generation methods. Instead it should accept the data to be rendered as a paremter.

Answer (score 3):

It is an important part of your role as the architect of your application to define what will be generated by helpers and what not, as it depends on what is repeated where and how often in your code. I am not going to tell you what to build helpers for because that depends on the architecture of your whole application. To help you make the decision, however, consider the two general types of helpers you can build: global and local.

Global helpers are for chunks of code which are often repeated across your site, possibly with a few minor changes that can be handled by passing in different parameters. Local helpers do the same job, but are local to a given page. A page which has a repeating segment of code that isn't really found anywhere else should implement a local helper. Now then...

Global helpers: Create a new static class to contain your helpers. Then, create static methods inside the container class that look like this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyHelper(this HtmlHelper helper, (the rest of your arguments here))
{
    // Create your HTML string.
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(your string);
}
```

What this does is create an extension method on the Html helper class which will allow you to access your helpers with the standard `Html.` syntax. Note that you will have to include the namespace of this class in any files where you want to use your custom helpers.

Local helpers: The other way to do helpers works when you want them to be local to a single view. Perhaps you have a block of code in a view that is being repeated over and over again. You can use the following syntax;

```
@helper MyHelper()
{
    // Create a string
    @MvcHtmlString.Create(your string here);
}
```

You can then output this onto your page using:

```
@MyHelper()
```

The reason why we are always creating `MvcHtmlString` objects is because as a security feature built into MVC, outputted strings are encoded to appear as they look in text on the page. That means that a `<` will be encoded so that you actually see a "<" on the page. It won't by default start an HTML tag.

To get around this, we use the `MvcHtmlString` class, which bypasses this security feature and allows us to output HTML directly to the page.

Comment: Why the downvote? Constructive criticism would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you move all this logic into a separate `Section` as it is a `Menu` that is being rendered.

Instead of building the HTML from the code, it is cleaner and a lot more convenient to build it using `Razor`'s `helper`s. Refer to [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx) as well as [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/12/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor.aspx) article from Scott Gu on how to render sections to get a quick starting guide.

Consider using Helper methods such as

[`@Html.DropDownListFor()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)  or
`@Html.DropDownList()`